# How to monitor incoming http requests

Tags: monitoring, web

How can I monitor incoming `HTTP` requests to port `80`? I have set up web hosting on my local machine using `DynDNS` and `Nginx`. **I wanted to know how many request are made on my server every day.**

Currently I'm using this command:

```
netstat -an | grep 80
```

Answer (score 49):

You may use `tcpdump`.

```
# tcpdump filter for HTTP GET 
sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'

# tcpdump filter for HTTP POST 
sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp dst port 80 and (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x504f5354)'
```

For a solution using `tshark` see:

https://serverfault.com/questions/84750/monitoring-http-traffic-using-tcpdump

Comment: That's so helpful. Is there something similar for thrift messages?

Comment: What about https?

Comment: would it be easy to use such a command for HTTPS (port 443) ?

Answer (score 7):

I've been using `tcpflow` to check incoming requests at aws instances, maybe there's a way to aggregate requests daywise.

**STEP 1 - installation**

```
# yum install --nogpgcheck http://pkgs.repoforge.org/tcpflow/tcpflow-0.21-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

**STEP 2 - track GET/POST requests at port 80**

```
# tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 | grep -oE '(GET|POST|HEAD) .* HTTP/1.[01]|Host: .*'
```

## Reference

https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow

Comment: For Ubuntu it's:
sudo apt install tcpflow
Also on Ubuntu the "eth0" is named something like "ens33".
You can use ifconfig command to see the name of your ethernet adaptor.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have log files turned on for your server? If you do, I'd recommend installing AwStats and running your log files with it to get accurate reporting.

If you want to just monitor all incoming/outgoing traffic, you can use WireShark.

Answer (score 4):

You can also tail the log file:

```
tail -f /path/to/access_log
```

The -f parameter will cause tail to continually update the screen as new entries are written to the log.

Answer (score 1):

Run this

```
while true
do
echo -----`date '+%r'` -----:
netstat -ant | grep :8080 | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
echo httpd processes: [`ps aux | grep httpd | wc -l`]
echo .
sleep 2
done
```

It will monitor traffic on 8080 port every 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use `ngrep`

```
sudo apt install ngrep

sudo ngrep -d any port 80
```

output :

```bash
interface: any
filter: ( port 80 ) and (ip || ip6)
#############################################
T <request-ip>:80 -> <host-ip>:80 [AP] #45
.........................
..................................
```